# Why is the tail call optimization not used in this Haskell program?

Tags: haskell, recursion, tail-call-optimization

The following program blows the stack:

```
__find_first_occurrence :: (Eq b) => b -> [b] -> Int -> Int
__find_first_occurrence e [] i = -1
__find_first_occurrence e (x:xs) i
    | e == x = i
    | otherwise = __find_first_occurrence e xs (i + 1)

find_first_occurrence :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Int
find_first_occurrence elem list =   
    __find_first_occurrence elem list 0

main = do
    let n = 1000000
    let idx = find_first_occurrence n [1..n]
    putStrLn (show idx)
```

Fails with

> Stack space overflow: current size 8388608 bytes. Use `+RTS -Ksize
>   -RTS' to increase it.

However, as far as I understand it, the possible recursive call to `__find_first_occurrence` is the last thing evaluated by `__find_first_occurrence`, hence tail call optimization should be possible to do.

Comment: TCO isn't all that useful in Haskell. Laziness usually takes care of that so you rarely need it. In this case, I think the problem is huge unevaulated thunk on `i`. Try to force `i` before doing recursive call.

Comment: I was wondering about the definition of the first pattern match in __find_first_occurrence, namely `__find_first_occurrence e l i =`. Is it possible that the problem is not reduced in that expression? (By the way, if you are looking for the first occurrence of something in a list, there's a built in function in Data.List: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:elemIndex , but I suppose that's not the point of the question:) )

Comment: @Christoffer: That case shouldn't be there at all. Oh, I just checked and indeed, `i \`seq\` __find_first_occurrence e xs (i + 1)` solves it.

Comment: @Christoffer This is a training program ;-) Sorry about the 2nd line, it was there by mistake.

Comment: @vitus - writing in the tail recursive style so you get TCO would be *very useful* for the function in question though, as it's answer doesn't want laziness.

Comment: I made a lazy evaluation version which doesn't use recursion:

`find_first_occurrence elem list = (snd . head) [x | x <- zip list [0..], fst x == elem]`

and it's much slower and uses much more memory.

Comment: @stephen tetley: Of course, there are cases where TCO is invaluable (e.g. accumulator patters). What I meant is that _generally_ you don't need TCO.

Comment: Note that by having the first clause return -1, the strictness analyser sees that the accumulator is not necessarily needed, so it can't make GHC evaluate the `i+1` in each step. If you used `i` also in the failure case, say with `__find_first_occurrence e [] i = -(i+1)`, the strictness analyser would cause it to be evaluated in each step (when compiling with optimisations, of course).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The tail call optimization is used, but the `(i+1)` expressions get thunked, and evaluating them at the end causes the stack to overflow.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more on why the (i+i) expression would get evaluated at the end. Is it because of lazy evaluation? Thank you.