# Time cost of Haskell `seq` operator

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, strict, seq

[This FAQ](http://users.aber.ac.uk/afc/stricthaskell.html#seq) says that

> The seq operator is
>
> ```
> seq :: a -> b -> b
> ```
>
> x `seq` y will evaluate x, enough to check that it is not bottom, then
>   discard the result and evaluate y. This might not seem useful, but it
>   means that x is guaranteed to be evaluated before y is considered.

That's awfully nice of Haskell, but does it mean that in

```
x `seq` f x
```

the cost of evaluating `x` will be paid twice ("discard the result")?

Comment: Perhaps "discard the result" is too strong. It discards the result in the same way `const` discards its second argument. If the argument has been evaluated, it doesn't somehow unevaluate it or throw away the result, it just ignores it. "x `seq` y will evaluate x, enough to check that it is not bottom, then _ignore_ the result and evaluate y" is perhaps a better way to phrase it.

Comment: It begins to dawn on me how different Haskell's computation model is from my core programming language (C++).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `seq` function will discard the value of `x`, but since the value has been evaluated, all references to `x` are "updated" to no longer point to the unevaluated version of `x`, but to instead point to the evaluated version. So, even though `seq` evaluates and discards `x`, the value has been evaluated for other users of `x` as well, leading to no repeated evaluations.

Answer (score 12):

No, it's not compute and forget, it's compute - which forces caching.

For example, consider this code:

```
 let x = 1 + 1
 in x + 1
```

Since Haskell is lazy, this evaluates to `((1 + 1) + 1)`.  A thunk, containing the sum of a thunk and one, the inner thunk being one plus one.

Let's use javascript, a non-lazy language, to show what this looks like:

```
 function(){
   var x = function(){ return 1 + 1 };
   return x() + 1;
 }
```

Chaining together thunks like this can [cause stack overflows, if done repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706589/why-is-the-tail-call-optimization-not-used-in-this-haskell-program), so `seq` to the rescue.

```
let x = 1 + 1
in x `seq` (x + 1)
```

I'm lying when I tell you this evaluates to `(2 + 1)`, but that's *almost* true - it's just that the calculation of the 2 is forced to happen before the rest happens (but the 2 is still calculated lazily).

Going back to javascript:

```
 function(){
   var x = function(){ return 1 + 1 };
   return (function(x){
     return x + 1;
   })( x() );
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe `x` will only be evaluated once (and the result retained for future use, as is typical for lazy operations).  That behavior is what makes `seq` useful.

Answer (score 1):

Of course [`seq` by itself does **not** "evaluate" anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149183/tail-optimization-guarantee-loop-encoding-in-haskell). It just records the forcing order dependency. The forcing itself is triggered by pattern-matching. When `seq x (f x)` is forced, `x` will be forced first (memoizing the resulting value), and then `f x` will be forced. Haskell's lazy evaluation means it memoizes the results of forcing of expressions, so no repeat "evaluation" (scary quotes here) will be performed.

I put "evaluation" into scary quotes because it implies **full** evaluation. In the words of [Haskell wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Laziness#Thunks_and_Weak_head_normal_form),

> *"Haskell values are highly layered; 'evaluating' a Haskell value could mean evaluating down to any one of these layers."*

**Let me reiterate: `seq` by itself does not evaluate anything.** `seq x x` does not evaluate `x` under any circumstance. `seq x (f x)` does not evaluate anything when `f = id`, contrary to what [the report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1260006.2) seems to have been saying.

Answer (score 1):

You can always check with `unsafePerformIO` or `trace`…

```
import System.IO.Unsafe (unsafePerformIO)

main = print (x `seq` f (x + x))
  where
    f = (+4)
    x = unsafePerformIO $ print "Batman!" >> return 3
```