# Haskell's `seq` evaluates arguments redundantly?

Tags: performance, haskell

If I understand the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707190/time-cost-of-haskell-seq-operator) correctly, `seq` should not be evaluating a value twice, as in `` x `seq` x `` should be evaluating `x` once.

Then why do I have this behaviour?

```
λ> :set +s
λ> let fib x = if x <= 1 then x else fib (x - 1) + fib (x - 2)
(0.01 secs, 102,600 bytes)
λ> fib 30
832040
(2.49 secs, 638,088,448 bytes)
λ> let x = fib 30 in x
832040
(2.47 secs, 638,088,792 bytes)
λ> let x = fib 30 in x `seq` x
832040
(4.95 secs, 1,276,067,128 bytes)
```

which is clearly double evaluating? Am I misunderstanding something?

**EDIT**: As asked @danidiaz below, I also evaluated

```
λ> (\x -> x `seq` x) (fib 30)
832040
(2.51 secs, 638,087,888 bytes)
λ> let x = (fib 30) :: Int in x `seq` x
832040
(2.52 secs, 732,476,640 bytes)
```

which are even more surprising now.

**EDIT 2:** I see that this question has been marked as a duplicate of an earlier question that asks about the monomorphism restriction. When I encountered this problem, I had no idea that this was due to the restriction. So if someone finds him/herself in my position I guess the answer to this question would be helpful.

Comment: What happens if you try `(\x -> x \`seq\` x) (fib 30)` and `let x = (fib 30) :: Int in x \`seq\` x` ?

Comment: Added to post, even more surprised now!

Comment: The problem is that `fib` has the polymorphic type `(Ord a, Num a) => a -> a`. Hence, in the expression ``x `seq` x``, the first `x` could be instantiated to a different monomorphic type than the second `x`. For example, the first `x` could be an `Int` whereas the second `x` could be a `Double`. There's nothing that forces the two to be the same type. That's the reason why `x` is evaluated twice.

Comment: The solution is simple. Give `fib` a explicit type signature like `let fib :: Int -> Int; fib x = if x <= 1 then x else fib (x - 1) + fib (x - 2)`.

Comment: Avoiding this kind of performance issues is, precisely, why the Monomorphism Restriction was introduced. Without the MR `x` is polymorphic and ``x `seq` x`` actually means something like ``x () `seq` x ()``, as if `x` were a function, and there `seq` will call the function twice (understandably).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the first part of this answer, `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction` in ghci. It will be explained later.

Naively, one would expect that in Haskell `let x = 5 in (x + 1,x + 2)` would always be equivalent to `(\x -> (x + 1, x + 2)) 5`. But they have different types!

```
let x = 5 in (x + 1,x + 2) :: (Num a, Num b) => (a, b)

(\x -> (x + 1,x + 2)) 5 :: Num b => (b, b)
```

The reason is a feature of Haskell called [let-bound polymorphism](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/pitfalls.html). Unlike lambda-bound identifiers, identifiers bound in a `let` can be instantiated in different ways in the body of the `let`. For example:

```
ghci> let f = id in (f True, f 'a')
(True,'a')

ghci> (\f -> (f True, f 'a')) id
*** ERROR ***
```

Now, you didn't give a type signature to your `fib` funtion, and the one that is deduced is something like

```
fib :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> a
```

that will work for different instances of `Num` like `Int`, `Float`, etc.

But because of this, when you write `` x `seq` x ``, ghci can't be sure that the two `x`s are actually of the same type! And if they might be different, then they can't be shared.

That's the reason why `` (\x -> x `seq` x) (fib 30) `` does have sharing. Because the `x` is lambda-bound, the compiler is sure that both occurrences really are the same value. Same for `` let x = (fib 30) :: Int in x `seq` x `` because we have removed polymorphism using an explicit type.

There's another way out. Turning on the [`-XMonomorphismRestriction`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction) extension increases the amount of type defaulting, causing `let` expressions to be more monomorphic than one might expect. That should be enough to recover sharing in this case as well.